# How to setup mediawiki Oauth extension on mediawiki 1.39

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to setup Oauth Extension on a mediawiki 1.39, https://github.com/CanastaWiki/Canasta-DockerCompose/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

As it is 1.39 i used https://extdist.wmflabs.org/dist/extensions/OAuth-REL1_39-1334c21.tar.gz

I created a certificate and put those variables in my LocalSettings

```
$wgOAuth2PrivateKey = "/oauth/oauth.key"
$wgOAuth2PublicKey = "/oauth/oauth.cert
```

I managed to register my Oauth 2.0 consumer on Special:OAuthConsumerRegistration

I got an app key, app secret, and token.

As detailed in : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers
I put the token as a Bearer in an Authorization header.

But if i test it on :

https://localhost/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json

I have the following error 500  :

```
MediaWiki internal error
.. ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
from /var/www/mediawiki/w/user-extensions/OAuth/vendor/lcobucci/clock/src/SystemClock.php(13)
```

Comment: Are two semicolons and a closing quote missing in the real `LocalSettings.php`, too?

Comment: Not sure how the localsettings would be relevant, the error appears to be in `/var/www/mediawiki/w/user-extensions/OAuth/vendor/lcobucci/clock/src/SystemClock.php`, line 13. So go check what's in that file.

Comment: @CBroe Yes it is linked to [this dependency](https://github.com/lcobucci/clock/blob/3.2.x/src/SystemClock.php#L13) 
can you explain 

`unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) `
is it related to the DateTimeZone variable ?

Comment: Looks like your PHP version is simply too low - this syntax was introduced in PHP 8.x, whereas it looks like you are still running a 7.x version?

Comment: It does seem to be the case, the canasta image uses php 7 only and is probably incompatible with this package then, thanks for the help.